# How to calculate win chance?

Tags: probability, gambling

I am trying to calculate win chance for the following game.
We have `9` indexed cells. One cell is green. User can select `N` cells (1-8) and reveal them. 
If the green cell was within revealed cells, then user won. What is the win probability for the given `N` number selected number, `1` green cell and `9` total cells?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the user choose how many cell he wants to open?

Comment: Yes, the user chooses how many cells to open, which is `M`. I've tried to see how close it is to Keno, but can't figure out yet.

Comment: There are $C(9,N)$ ways to select $N$ cells. Since there are exactly $8$ non-green sells, there are $C(8,N)$ ways to select $N$ cells with no green cells...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\frac N9$ chance of finding the green cell if you pick $N$ cells.  Each pick has a disjoint $\frac 19$ chance of winning.